# VB.NET Connection to LDAP fails unknown username or bad password

Tags: vb.net

I would really welcome some help with this issue.  We have a php code that works and connects to the LDAP.  When I try to connect using VB.NET 2010, it fails to bind with logon failure unknown username or bad password.  Below is the connection information.  When I talk to the folks who run the ldap server, they say I am binding sucessfully, below is the log file for the sucessful bind?  If I continue and try to execute a search I don't get any results.  The server is running openLDAP ver 2.3.39 on a linux server, server requires connection on port 636 for secure connection, or 389 for anonymous.

using the following imports in code:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.DirectoryServices.Protocols
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Net.NetworkCredential
```

my connection:

```
Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.MyDomain.xxx/cn=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=xxx", "uid=my-bind,cn=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=xxx", "MyPassword")
 dirEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer
```

my BindLog:

> Mar 16 15:10:17 ldap4 slapd[17391]:
>   conn=110556 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0
>   text= Mar 16 15:10:17 ldap4
>   slapd[17391]: conn=110555 op=0 BIND
>   dn="uid=my-bind,cn=users,dc=myDomain,dc=xxx"
>   method=128 Mar 16 15:10:17 ldap4
>   slapd[17391]: conn=110555 op=0 BIND
>   dn="uid=my-bind,cn=users,dc=myDomain.xxx"
>   mech=SIMPLE ssf=0 Mar 16 15:10:17
>   ldap4 slapd[17391]: conn=110555 op=0
>   RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=

my search:

```
Try
            Dim search As New DirectorySearcher(enTry)
            search.Filter = ("(&(objectClass=users)(cn=" & myUser & "))")

            Dim result As SearchResult = search.FindOne()
            Dim myResult As Boolean = Nothing
            If result Is Nothing Then
                myResult = False
            Else
                myResult = True
            End If
            .... do some processing here

        Catch f As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(f.Message & vbCrLf & f.HelpLink.ToString)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.MyDomain.xxx/cn=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=xxx",
> ```
>
> "uid=my-bind,cn=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=xxx", "MyPassword")

The constuctor you're trying to use is probably this

```
Public Sub New(ByVal path As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
```

but your passing "uid=my-bind,cn=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=xxx" as the username.

Comment: If I make the change to the following I receive the follow error:

Comment: if I make the change to Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.myDomain.xxx/cn=users,dc=myDomain,dc=xxx", "my-bind", "myPassword")  I get the following error:  an invalid dn syntax has been specified.

Comment: if I change my dn to path = ("LDAP://xxx.myDomain.xxx:636:/cn=users,dc=myDomaon,dc=xxx","myBind","myPassword")  The error I will get is login failure, or a device attached to the system is no longer functioning.

Comment: I was never able to connect LDAP.  I had made an effort to search the web prior to posting.  I checked and changed and tried every possible solution.  I was able to finally get in, but I downloaded the code from sourceForge here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetopenldap.aspx and compiled it. for the ldap_net.dll added it to my program as a refrence and import ldap_net for my imports.  This worked like a champ!  The search feature works well, but took me a second to modify to meet my needs.  Thank you for responding MHollis,  nice to know someone is looking.